# Отмена state aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Как отменить state в любой момент? Условно бот присылает человеку такое сообщение:

"Введите свой возраст:"

И условно если пользователь пропишет "/start" то состояние должно сброситься/отмениться. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш код следующий хэндлер:

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Все состояния сброшены')
```

при отправке `/cancel` (*ну или пропишите любую свою команду*) все состояния будут сброшены